# Removing white artifacts from composition

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, freestyle

I'm trying to compose two layers into a single one. The first layer contains the image itself and the second one the lines from freestyle. Here are my nodes: [image]

I want the first layer to have some lower opacity while the second one to be completely opaque. However whenever I join both layers some white artifact appear around the lines. How I convert then to the color of the line itself? If I connect the freestyle layer to viewer it seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this transparent color to black (also transparent, but base on black):

[image]

Also try z-combine instead of Alpha Over:

[image]

Comment: Worked as expected! I will work to understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing